# Why can't I insert a row into my database when I use @ManyToOne?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have these entities.

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Language {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String language;
    
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sentence {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String wordInFrench;
    
    @NotNull
    private String wordInOtherLanguage;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    private Language language;
    
}
```

When I try to insert a row into the `sentence` database by using this code:

```
// My repository
private SentenceRepository sentenceRepository;

// Object information
Long id = 0L; 
String wordInFrench = "Oui oui"
String wordInOtherLanguage = "Ja ja"
Language language = new Language(id, "Swedish");

// Save to database
sentenceRepository.save(new Sentence(id, wordInFrench, wordInOtherLanguage, language));
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find 
    se.danielmartensson.entity.Language with id 0; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find se.danielmartensson.entity.Language with id 0

    Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find se.danielmartensson.entity.Language with id 0
```

And if I use `Long id = 1L;` then I get this error as well:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find 
se.danielmartensson.entity.Language with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find se.danielmartensson.entity.Language with id 1

Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find se.danielmartensson.entity.Language with id 1
```

So what is happening? Why can't I insert a `sentence` into the database and the `language` database will updates as well?

Comment: I think you need a database reference of your language. That means you should persist it first in two steps or @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST) may be

Comment: @Novy Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Hibernate is trying to find a `Language` instance in the database with id = 0 (and 1), but it isn't there.

First you must insert the Language and only after this you can insert the Sentence:

```
// My repositories
private LanguageRepository languageRepository;
private SentenceRepository sentenceRepository;

// Inserting the Language
Language language = new Language();
language.setLanguage("Swedish");
// Here, note that I'm not forcing the value of the attribute "id". 
// The "@GeneratedValue" will generate one for me.

// Also note that the "save" method returns an object. In this case, 
// it will be a "Language" instance with the new id
language = languageRepository.save(language);

// Inserting the Sentence
Sentence sentence = new Sentence();
sentence.setWordInFrench("Oui oui");
sentence.setWordInOtherLanguage("Ja ja");
sentence.setLanguage(language);

sentenceRepository.save(sentence);
```

Anternatively, you can do:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sentence {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String wordInFrench;
    
    @NotNull
    private String wordInOtherLanguage;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_language", nullable = false)
    private Language language;
```

We're using `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to indicate that, every time we try to insert a new Sentence, Hibernate will automatically check if the `language` object is already present in the database. If not, the `language` will be inserted beforehand.
Besides, for foreign keys, it's suggested to use the `@JoinColumn` Mapping to configure the column definitions like "name", "nullable", "unique", etc.

Comment: The alternative suggestion does not work, but I'm sure that I need to use cascade Presist or something?

Comment: `CascadeType.PERSIST` is meant to be an extra useful configuration, but is totally optional. What went wrong with the alternative solution? Is there an error log that you can show me? And what about the first solution? Did it work?

Comment: Your first example works =). First to save the language, then save the sentence by including the language there. PRESIST gave an error and said that it could not handle PRESIST.

Comment: By the way! If you want to try the simple application, you can download it from here. Just open maven and run "mvn spring-boot:run" inside the folder of the project. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Learn-French Notice you need MySQL database as well :)